# Optimize MySQL Query on Multiple NOT INs

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to optimize this sql statement? 
Maybe joins or something?

```
SELECT id, name
FROM item
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id 
FROM itemlock
) AND id NOT IN (
SELECT id
    FROM itemlog
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    item a
        LEFT JOIN itemLock b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
        LEFT JOIN itemLog c
            ON a.ID = c.ID
WHERE   b.ID IS NULL AND 
        c.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use UNION, like below:

```
SELECT id, name FROM item 
WHERE id NOT IN (
   SELECT id  FROM itemlock UNION SELECT id FROM itemlog
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, NAME FROM item i 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM itemlock 
    UNION 
    SELECT id FROM itemlog) AS A ON i.id = A.id 
WHERE A.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I tried to run this but unfortunately, this is slower than my original script. Unions might be making things slower. :-(